# What's the easiest way to find rows of data that are causing errors in Query?

Tags: postgresql

I'm getting an error when I run a query due to a couple of lines of my source data having decimals when they should not. I need to pinpoint these specific rows so I can correct them in the source data but I do not know how to find them. Is there an easy way to pinpoint the rows that are causing the error?

Comment: Providing a table definition, sample data and expected output would increase the chance of getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your data is improperly typed, you have a text or varchar data type for what should be numeric class type. If so that needs to be corrected, but yes you must fix the data first. You can to isolate and fix the incorrect rows by selecting those which *fail a regexp that defines a valid value*.  Since you did not post sample data nor table descriptions only provide an example that I make up, **not** your values.

Example:  
 
 - For just digits only: column_name !~ '^[0-9]+$'  
 
 - For Positive or Negative Integer: column_name !~ '^(+|-)?[0-9]+$'

```
with test (id,num_val) as
     ( values (1,'abc'),(2,'18'),(3,'1.7'),(4,'-12') )
select id, num_val, 'Fails Just Digits'
  from test
 where num_val !~ '^[0-9]+$'
union
select id, num_val, 'Fails Pos/Neg Integer'
  from test
 where num_val !~ '^(\+|-)?[0-9]+$'
order by 1,3;
```

1. fails both
2. passes both (so not in output)
3. fails both
4. fails Just digits